# How to move folder using command line in WIN 32 API?

Tags: winapi, command, directory, move

I'm trying to move KFC folder from D drive to C drive using command line in WIN32 API. In KFC folder has an other folder: "New Folder".
I try to using this code but it can't?

```
CreateProcess(  L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",// path to application to run command
                                _T("/C MD C:\\KFC"),
                                NULL, 
                                NULL, 
                                FALSE, 
                                CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
                                NULL, 
                                NULL, 
                                &startupInfo, 
                                &processInformation );
CreateProcess(  L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",// path to application to run command
                                _T("/C XCOPY D:\\KFC C:\\KFC /E"),
                                NULL, 
                                NULL, 
                                FALSE, 
                                CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
                                NULL, 
                                NULL, 
                                &startupInfo, 
                                &processInformation );


CreateProcess(  L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",// path to application to run command
                                _T("/C RD D:\\KFC /S/Q"),
                                NULL, 
                                NULL, 
                                FALSE, 
                                CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
                                NULL, 
                                NULL, 
                                &startupInfo, 
                                &processInformation );
```

Thanks for helping,

Comment: Would it be easier to use `SHFileOperation`?

Comment: I'm using C/C++ progamming. Can SHFileOperation use with folder ( I think it is used with File not folder)?

Comment: Like it says in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), "Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally *repeat the module name as the first token in the command line*." In other words, the second parameter should be `_T("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /C MD C:\\KFC")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `SHFileOperation`; for example:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT sfo = { 0 };
sfo.wFunc = FO_MOVE;
sfo.pFrom = _T("D:\\KFC\0");
sfo.pTo = _T("C:\\\0");
sfo.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
SHFileOperation(&sfo);
```

Note that the `pFrom` and `pTo` strings are both double-NULL terminated.

If you want to hide the progress bars etc you can do this with the `FOF_NO_UI` flag or other options.

You can also use the `IFileOperation` interface in a similar way.

Comment: wFunc = FO_DELETE; Docs are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795(v=vs.85).aspx